# How to get the BBM connected apps list pragmatically BB 10 cascades

Tags: blackberry-10, cascade, blackberry-cascades, bb-messenger

I am working on BB 10 cascades BBM. I have a requirement as when I install my app, app automatically add to BBM connect apps list and how can I show the list BBM connected apps.

Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke BBM and use the "invite to BBM" feature to add contacts to BBM.  Your application can pre-populate the invite list.  There isn't a way to do this without some user interaction.  Details on the invocation can be found here:  https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/bbm.html

There isn't a way to programmatically obtain a list of BBM connected apps.  But you can obtain a list of the user's BBM contacts who also have your application installed.  This sample shows how to do that:  https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/bbmcontacts